# push local repository to gitlab new project and get pre-receive hook declined

Tags: git, git-push

```
Locking support detected on remote "origin". Consider enabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://192.168.5.11/sc/packer.git/info/lfs.locksverify true
Git LFS upload missing objects:16), 315 MB | 0 B/s                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  (missing) packer (a1744b0e8f98ddff97ae7beaccc37561ea5b9106891feed88cf06e453f34465d)
  (missing) packer-builder-vsphere-iso.linux (6e432cc39503ac6604564ba33aaf10d7debb6b6d20429b0af168a00bee342c3b)
Uploading LFS objects:  25% (4/16), 315 MB | 0 B/s, done.
Counting objects: 318, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (165/165), done.
Writing objects: 100% (318/318), 25.82 MiB | 19.76 MiB/s, done.
Total 318 (delta 160), reused 297 (delta 146)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (160/160), done.
remote: GitLab: LFS objects are missing. Ensure LFS is properly set up or try a manual "git lfs push --all".To git@192.168.5.11:sc/packer.git
 ! [remote rejected] init -> init (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@192.168.5.11:sc/packer.git'
```

Hi all, I'm having one git push related issue, the steps are as follows:

1. I first created 1 project packer on gitlab;
2. Upload the previously saved libraries to packer, and when you execute the following commands separately, you find that 2.2 is abnormal

   2.1  `git remote rename origin old-origin`

   2.2  `git remote add origin git@192.168.5.11:sc/packer.git`

   2.3  `git push -u origin --all`

   2.4  `git push -u origin --tags`

When I looked up this anomaly on Google, I found that most of it was related to unprotected branches.
But my project is new, and there are no branches in it.
In addition, I still report this exception when I create a new branch locally.
What can I do next to fix this exception?

Comment: To add up, the original uploaded account did not have commit permissions, and the user.name content was updated later, and it is still invalid.
git config --global --replace-all user.name “xxxxxx”